# What are modules in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

I would like to know about modules in CodeIgniter, and where can I learn how to develop modules?

Answer (score 2):

As far as Codeigniter (out of the box) is concerned, `Modules` in terms of HMVC patterning, do not exist.

Codeigniter does have a `package` system ([As part of the loader class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html)) that does allow you to use third party "packages" in a segregated directory.  [But make sure to note that packages are not the same as modules](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2010/04/codeigniter-packages-modules).

If you are interested in using HMVC modules in Codeigniter, there are some [third party ways to accomplish this.](http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/72123/)

Comment: I mean modules folder in some CMS based on CodeIgniter.What does that folder means?How does folder work? sorry if I make mistake ... Thanks for your answer.

Comment: CMS based on CodeIgniter like pyrocms , ionizecms

Comment: Every CMS implements their own "module" system and would be completely different, you would have to consult the specific CMS's documentation.

Comment: Yes ... that's right, jondavidjohn.I want to know is how to develop modules by myself. any reference links to learn?